# Does chromium store our passwords in passwords.google.com if we let it manage passwords?

Tags: password, chromium

I noticed some changes in the chromium settings. It goes something like "Access your passwords from any device at passwords.google.com".

I noticed chromium still uses the keyring to store passwords, but is chromium also storing our freaking passwords in the google cloud?

1. Will chromium sync the passwords if I don't login to a google account? I guess the answer is "no".
2. Will chromium sync the passwords if I do login to a google account, even if I never click the link passwords.google.com? I guess the answer is "yes". I very much don't like this.

What do you think?

Regards

Comment: In Chromium and Chrome you can choose what to sync. And you can manage already synced data.

Comment: There is a comprehensive review of managing your passwords here - https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

Comment: Hi, Panther: In that link they say "If you've saved passwords to Smart Lock for Passwords or to Chrome while signed in, you can also see and delete your saved passwords at passwords.google.com.". It makes me think that if I log in to google from chrome, it will automatically send my passwords to google...

Comment: AlexP, can we tell me where I can configure waht to sync. I only see a button for disabling password management altogether. Do you mean I have to log in to passwords.google.com to tell them I don't want them to keep my passwords?